# Definir cor célula listview para palavras especificas

Tags: c#

Preciso que ao carregar dados específicos no listview a célula em questão seja formatada com cor definida.O código abaixo formata a linha inteira e preciso que formate apenas a célula definida.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvDados.Items)
                    {
                        if (item.SubItems[18].Text == "VENCIDO") item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        else item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    }
```

Como ficaria o código para formatar apenas a célula ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código para formatação do subitem

```
                                 lsvDados.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;//para que a formataçao do item nao se propague ao subitem
                                 foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvDados.Items)
                                {
                                if (item.SubItems[18].Text == "Vencido") 
                                item.SubItems[18].BackColor =  System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                                else 
                                item.SubItems[18].BackColor =   System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                                 }
```

> Também informado pelo @Emerson js,
>
> Seu código está correto, porém faltou um detalhe que faz toda a
>   diferença: configurar a propriedade UseItemStyleForSubItems.
>
> Quando você criar seus itens para popular o ListView eles devem ter a
>   propriedade UseItemStyleForSubItems configurada para o valor false.
>
> Quando o valor é true, cada SubItem ficará com o mesmo estilo
>   configurado no Item, mesmo que você altere sua cor de fundo, fonte,
>   etc...
>
> Documentação da MSDN - UseItemStyleForSubItems
>
> Resumindo:
>
> Quando popular o ListView faça:
>                                  ListViewItem i1 = new ListViewItem("1");
>
> ```
>                            i1.SubItems.Add("Valor Coluna 1...");
>                            i1.SubItems.Add("Valor Coluna 2...");
>                            i1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false; // para cada item Daí pode fazer a formatação normalmente.
> ```

[Formatar subitem listview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137491/formatar-subitem-listview)