# Formatar subitem listview

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho problemas para definir cor de fundo do SubItem do listview quando  retornar consulta do banco de dados. Preciso que na coluna n° 18, a qual retornará valores como " Vencido" e " Em Dia" , quando o valor retornado for = a "Vencido" esse subitem da coluna 18 fique com fundo vermelho. O código abaixo colore a linha completa.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvDados.Items)
                {
                    if (item.SubItems[18].Text == "VENCIDO") 
                    item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    else item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
```

O código abaixo não colore nada.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lsvDados.Items)
                {
                     if (item.SubItems[18].Text == "Vencido") 
                     item.SubItems[18].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                     else 
                     item.SubItems[18].BackColor =System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                 }
```

Como faço pra colorir apenas o subitem com o valor desejado ?
Como ficaria o código para varrer todo o listview a procura de algum subitem com esse valor desejado e logo apos encontrar  formata-lo ?

Comment: @Emerson JS, O código formata apenas um valor retornado do banco. Caso o select retorne 3 linhas, apenas a 1 sera formatada. Porque isso ocorre, deveria formatar todas as linhas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está correto, porém faltou um detalhe que faz toda a diferença: configurar a propriedade `UseItemStyleForSubItems`.

Quando você criar seus itens para popular o `ListView` eles devem ter a propriedade `UseItemStyleForSubItems` configurada para o valor **false**.

Quando o valor é **true**, cada *SubItem* ficará com o mesmo estilo configurado no *Item*, mesmo que você altere sua cor de fundo, fonte, etc...

[Documentação da MSDN - UseItemStyleForSubItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.useitemstyleforsubitems(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Resumindo:

- Quando popular o `ListView` faça:

  ```
      ListViewItem i1 = new ListViewItem("1");

      i1.SubItems.Add("Valor Coluna 1...");
      i1.SubItems.Add("Valor Coluna 2...");
      i1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false; // para cada item
  ```

Daí pode fazer a formatação normalmente.

Comment: @ Emerson Entendi, vou aplicar essa propriedade, agora ficou claro. Muito obrigado